# How to use ::date in java JDBC hibernate?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, timestamp, spring-jdbc

### PG Admin

I have a query on SQL Editor in PGadmin:

```
select * from list_taxi where last_update::date = now()::date
```

It show a good result, It show the taxi that online/update today. 
(I use ::date).
Then I implement the query into Java using hibernate.

### Java - JDBC Hibernate

I have a timestamp variable

```
Timestamp nowTime = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() );
```

I have query in Java DAO connected to Postgresql (JDBC - Hibernate)

```
ArrayList<Object[]> arrayList = 
(ArrayList) em.createQuery("SELECT lt FROM ListTaxi lt 
WHERE lt.lastUpdate::date = '" + nowTime + "'::date ")
.getResultList();
```

The result is error because of `::date`

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: 
: near line 1, column 75 [SELECT lt FROM model.ListTaxi lt WHERE 
lt.lastUpdate::date = lt.lastUpdate::date]
```

How to solve this?

Comment: try em.createQuery("FROM ListTaxi  ....) instead of em.createQuery("SELECT lt FROM ListTaxi ...). SELECT * part, it's implicit

Comment: Thanks, I did it. But I still get the error. I think the problem is about the using of ::date in Java.. (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: : near line 1, column 65 [FROM model.ListTaxi lt WHERE lt.lastUpdate::date = lt.lastUpdate::date])

Comment: Try em.createQuery(" FROM ListTaxi lt 
WHERE lt.lastUpdate = :nowTime)
.getResultList();

Comment: @stackUser44: That will only match if the timestamp matches exactly, not just "today"

Comment: em.createQuery(" FROM ListTaxi lt order by lt.lastUpdate  desc ).setFirstResult(0).setMaxResults(1).getResultList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround you can do

```
WHERE lastUpdate > :startOfTodayTimestamp  -- set this to :00:00:00 today
```

If you have dates from the future or want to do this not just with today, you also need to add an upper bound.

Comment: I searched a bit around on Stackoverflow, but could not find a neat solution that does not drop down into native SQL). The good thing about this workaround is also that it is very index-friendly (which some of the conversions may not be).

Comment: `java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
        today.setHours(0);
        today.setMinutes(0);
        today.setSeconds(0);
        Timestamp startOfTodayTimestamp = new Timestamp(today.getTime());`

Comment: Great Idea!! I solved this problem by your idea, thank you so much master